# How to avoid temporary folders creation under /tmp while submitting Spark job using spark-submit?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

I am using Apache Spark 2.4 and submitting 3K-4K Spark jobs daily on YARN resource manager using 'Cluster mode'.

Problem: Every time when I submit a job via spark-submit it creates temporary folders in /tmp (on edge/gateway node), since cluster is multi-tenant (other teams also doing the same on gateway node) /tmp folder is keep getting 100% full and am not able to submit Spark jobs.

I have tried to run jobs with below config but still spark-submit is creating one folder in /tmp and remaining folders in /ops/data/tmp

spark.local.dir=/ops/data/tmp

Could you please advise how to completely avoid the usage of /tmp folder on edge node. thank you

Comment: According to documentation this might be overriden by LOCAL_DIRS variabel by Yarn. Have you checked that? c.f. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: @Paul, thank you for your reply.
I have already checked that LOCAL_DIRS overrides path in container(s) while running in cluster mode.

Comment: Change yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs to different folder with more space and restart all NodeManagers in cluster.